# How get ASCII from CHAR in Office365

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, office365

I'm trying to learn how to build an Office365 Add-In to MS-Word.

My problem is to get the ASCII-code of characters in text, since Office Javascript seems not have .charAt() function (although it has fromCharAt()).

I had tried:
  - var.prototype.charAt()
  - var.charAt()  << does not exist

My routine is:

```
    var CurrentIndex = text.length,
        V_Temp,
        AsciiV_Temp;
    while (0 !== CurrentIndice) {
        CurrentIndex -= 1;
        V_Temp = text[CurrentIndex];
        AsciiV_Temp = ??????
    }
```

I would like to know how can I implement a function to do this or, in another way, if I can call a .NET Class to perform this function.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not clear in your code whether text is a string or an array. I assume it's an array because you use text[CurrentIndex].

If it's a string, you need text.substr(CurrentIndex,1).

In either case .charCodeAt() should return the ascii value.

Comment: @TonyDuffill, I don't have this instruction in the Javascript of Office365 Add-In!  That's the problem!! I have the opposite instruction .FromCodeAt() but NOT the .CharCodeAt() or ANY similar. Weird!

Comment: Ah! - very odd, as you say. I know javascript but not Office365 add-in, I'm afraid. The last I heard it was still in Beta mode which may explain missing  bits.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-round which will return the ascii value (it assumes you are using characters: space to ~ (32 to 126).

```
var ascVals="";
for (k=32; k < 127; k++) {
    ascVals+=String.fromCharCode(k);
}
alert(ascVals.indexOf("a")+32);
```

Will return 97. Replacing "a" with your CharacterForAsciiConversion will at least give you the value until you have a better solution.

Comment: Thank you very much Tony, but since I'm working in documents with a lot of pages (in average, 70 pages), although a correct deviation, it's really unpractible in the real life. Anyway, I really appreciated your efforts and the spent time. Hugs!